# Prevent new WordPress users from logging in until manually "activated"?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, registration, user-management

I'm developing a plugin for WordPress which has 3 groups of users.  I need to disable some users and prevent them from login.  what I mean isn't preventing them to access the backend.  I want to prevent them from is log in.  For example, when they want to login they should see a message like this account isn't active yet.
thank you guys.

Comment: you can use the Meta_post in code or you can use existing user and apply condition in code of the pages.

Comment: this option is not possible in my situation.I need exactly prevent from login

Answer (score 14, accepted):

after some search and see similar problems I solved this problam like this :
first add a user meta for user status so we can checking if user is active or not then we can disable or enable users.

```
add_filter( 'authenticate', 'chk_active_user',100,2);
function chk_active_user ($user,$username) 
   {
     $user_data = $user->data;
     $user_id = $user_data->ID;
     $user_sts = get_user_meta($user_id,"user_active_status",true);
     if ($user_sts==="no")
     {
        return new WP_Error( 'disabled_account','this account is disabled');

      }
      else
      {
       return $user;
      }
        return $user;
     }
```